# Typescript Property 'label' does not exist on type 'string

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, vscode-extensions

I use the following code

```
    interface State {
        resourceGroup: QuickPickItem | string;

    }
```

```
setEvent(state.resourceGroup?.label).catch(err => console.error(err));
```

And for it I got the following error

```
any
Property 'label' does not exist on type 'string | QuickPickItem'.
  Property 'label' does not exist on type 'string'.
```

https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#QuickPickItem

Any idea how to avoid this error? **without suppressing it with ts-ignore** As im not able to change the `QuickPickItem` ...

**update**

I try to do the suggestion in the answer and still got the same error

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you will need to differentiate between the two possible values in the union type you have.

For example you can make sure that the value is not a string. that way typescript will infer that the value is of type `QuickPickItem`

```
interface State {     
  resourceGroup: QuickPickItem | string;   
}

let state: State = getState();

if (typeof state.resourceGroup != 'string' && state.resourceGroup?.label){
  setEvent(...)
}
```

You can read more about it in the typescript handbook.
[Type Guards and Differentiating Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types)

Answer (score 0):

Easiest is to test for the existence of the `label` property in your variable:

```
if(state.resourceGroup.label) {
   setEvent(state.resourceGroup.label).catch(err => console.error(err));
}
```

Other (unsafe - so only if you are 100% sure what you are doing) way is to use the exclamation mark to assert the existence of the porperty manually:

```
setEvent(state.resourceGroup.label!).catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Comment: if I use it like this `if (state.resourceGroup.label) {` I got error also for the if (same error) `(property) resourceGroup?: string | QuickPickItem | undefined
Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532)`

Comment: @BenoOdr you will need to use the optional chaining operator also to avoid the undefined issue

`if(state.resourceGroup?.label) {
   setEvent(state.resourceGroup.label).catch(err => console.error(err));
}`

Comment: @eltonkamami , when I do that`if (state.resourceGroup?.label) {`  I got the same error "property "label" does not exist

Comment: you can make sure its not a string with 
`if(typeof state.resourceGroup != 'string') console.log(state.resourceGroup.label)`

Comment: @eltonkamami - that work, you can add it as answer , one question currently I use `  `if (typeof state.resourceGroup != 'string') {
   if (state.resourceGroup?.label) {`is there a shorter way to do it insted of two if statments?

Comment: you can combine them in one if statement `if (typeof state.resourceGroup != 'string' && state.resourceGroup?.label){setEvent(...)}`